# Create a datetime with a list in python

Tags: python, datetime, for-loop, time, tuples

I want to create a `.datetime()` with a list of numbers.
I have a tuple through which I can iterate through to get the year, month, day, hour, minute and second printed on separate lines. I want to convert the `time` tuple to a `datetime` object.

Here is the code:

```
import datetime
time = (2020, 7, 24, 10, 54, 40)

for t in time:
    print(t)
```

If I do something like: `datetime.datetime(time)` it does not work.

I have searched on google but couldn't find an answer. If someone could point me towards the right direction, I will be grateful.
Thank you

Comment: `datetime.datetime(*time)`?

Comment: See in detail: https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/11/python-datetime-time-conversions/